# Entity Framework, Dynamic requested entity

Tags: .net, database, linq, entity-framework, mapping

I have a database mapped with EF 5.0.0

I'm displaying data in some lists. My data is retrieved in the "classic way" :

```
using (myContext db = new myContext())
{

    var products = db.products.Select(p => p).ToList();
}
```

I have to do this as much as tables I have,

is there any way to make this Dynamically ? :

```
using (myContext db = new myContext())
{
    type currentType = myTable1Type
    var currentList = db.currentType.Select(p => p).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`DbContext.Set` Method (Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
using (myContext db = new myContext())
{
    type currentType = myTable1Type
    var currentList = db.Set(currentType).Select(p => p).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Context.Set() method group.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me:

```
IDbSet GetDbSet(Type currentType, Context db)
{
    dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(currentType);
    return GetDbSetFromInstance(instance, db);
}

IDbSet GetDbSetFromInstance<T>(T instance, Context db)
    where T : class
{
    var set = db.Set<T>();
    if (set == null)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    return set;
}
```